# Python Pandas groupby mean with "No numeric types to aggregate" error

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to calculate one column mean from an excel.
I delete all the null value and '-' in the column called 'TFD' and form a new dataframe by selecting three columns. I want to calculated the mean from the new dataframe with groupby. But there is an error called "No numeric types to aggregate", I don't know why I have this error and how to fix it.
[image]

```
sheet=pd.read_excel(file)
sheet_copy=sheet
sheet_copy=sheet_copy[(~sheet_copy['TFD'].isin(['-']))&(~sheet_copy['TFD'].isnull())]
sheet_copy=sheet_copy[['Participant ID','Paragraph','TFD']]
means=sheet_copy['TFD'].groupby([sheet_copy['Participant ID'],sheet_copy['Paragraph']]).mean()
```

Answer (score 0):

From your spreadsheet snippet above it looks as though your Participant ID and Paragraph columns have data types which are Text formats which leads me to believe that they will be strings inside of your dataframe? Which leads me to believe this is precisely where your issue lies from the exception "No numeric types to aggregate"

Following this, here are some good examples of group by with the mean clause from the pandas documentation:

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.mean.html

If you had the dataset to hand I would have tried it out myself and provided a snippet of the code used.

Comment: Hello！I just solved it by  adding 'sheet_copy=sheet_copy.astype(float)'.

Comment: perfect! It's always a nuisance when importing an excel sheet directly into pandas - its worth checking the types of the variables to be used. Glad you found the issue :)